# Canon Selphy CP780 Printer for MacBook Air

Tags: macos, printing, driver

Where can I find information on set up?

Comment: Be aware that up to now there is no OS X 10.7 driver for the Selphy printers and some people have gotten support answers from Canon suggesting that there will be none.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should try the [GutenPrint print drivers](http://gimp-print.sourceforge.net/). These open source drivers work for a huge number of printers, the Selphy CP770 and 790 are listed as supported so either of those might work.

The drivers work with all versions of OS X.

Comment: Just a note: issues with Gutenprint on Catalina onwards (due IIUC to Apple's code-signing): https://sourceforge.net/p/gimp-print/bugs/723/

Answer (score 0):

Apple's Mac 101 guides for installing a printer: [Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3771), or [earlier versions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2495).

Canon's [extra drivers](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/printers_multifunction/compact_photo_printers/selphy_cp780#DriversAndSoftware) (you probably don't need them, but install if you have a problem).

Hope this helps. If you have a specific problem, please post with more details.